# Add a value to every element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I have this:

```
coordinates =
['54.9712958,-1.6094327',
 '54.9697686,-1.6138101',
 '54.969436,-1.6154838',
 '54.9691035,-1.6177368',
 '54.9685369,-1.619947',
 '54.968463,-1.6229939']
```

and I want something like this (add 100 to every value in the list):

```
coordinates =
[(54.9712958,-1.6094327,100),
 (54.9697686,-1.6138101,100),
 (54.969436,-1.6154838,100),
 (54.9691035,-1.6177368,100),
 (54.9685369,-1.619947,100),
 (54.968463,-1.6229939, 100)]
```

thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

- split on comma
- parse to `float`
- add the `100`

---

Using list-comprehension

```
coordinates = [(*list(map(float, item.split(","))), 100) for item in coordinates]
```

Using a loop

```
result = []
for item in coordinates:
  values = item.split(",")
  result.append((float(values[0]), float(values[1]), 100))
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you @azro !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a (nested) list comrehension ([[Python 3.Docs]: Data Structures - List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).

One thing to note is in the current state, each *coordinates* element is a string, which needs a bit of processing in order to extract the *float*s from it.

> ```py
> >>> coordinates = ['54.9712958,-1.6094327', '54.9697686,-1.6138101', '54.969436,-1.6154838', '54.9691035,-1.6177368', '54.9685369,-1.619947', '54.968463,-1.6229939']
> >>>
> >>> [(*(float(item1) for item1 in item0.split(",")), 100) for item0 in coordinates]
> [(54.9712958, -1.6094327, 100), (54.9697686, -1.6138101, 100), (54.969436, -1.6154838, 100), (54.9691035, -1.6177368, 100), (54.9685369, -1.619947, 100), (54.968463, -1.6229939, 100)]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through all of the coordinates, split them on comma (to get the x and y) and then make a tuple with those values and 100
You can then append that to some new list

```py
coordinates = [
    '54.9712958,-1.6094327',
    '54.9697686,-1.6138101',
    '54.969436,-1.6154838',
    '54.9691035,-1.6177368',
    '54.9685369,-1.619947',
    '54.968463,-1.6229939'
 ]

new_coords = []

for coord_pair in coordinates:
    coord_pair = coord_pair.split(",")
    new_coords.append((float(coord_pair[0]), float(coord_pair[1]), 100))
```

The `new_coords` variable is:

```py
[
    (54.9712958, -1.6094327, 100), 
    (54.9697686, -1.6138101, 100), 
    (54.969436, -1.6154838, 100), 
    (54.9691035, -1.6177368, 100), 
    (54.9685369, -1.619947, 100), 
    (54.968463, -1.6229939, 100)
]
```

*Note that I'm not sure if you want to have the 100 as int or float, in case you need float, just change the `100` to `float(100)` or `100.0`*

Comment: Sorry for my first response, I have misread the question, now it should work

Comment: Still a mix of strings and a number. and if you fix the strings, your code is the long version of the 2 already posted ones :)

Comment: I have fixed the string/number issue, but I respect that there are shorter answers. I aimed more for readability